# Labelling a contour plot and showing true values rather than density in R

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, contour

I am trying to create a contour plot of data in lists rather than a matrix like most of the examples available. I have tried filled conotur plots in the base code and had issues such as "object x not found". I was referred to using the ggplot2 stat_density2d. Although this produces the type of plot I am after I am having trouble customising it. Does anybody know how to label the contours with their values if you are using the geom_density2d variable? Also does anybody know how to make the key show the actual value rather than the desnity? I have the feeling I am using the wrong function to portray the true values but don't know how to manipulate the filled.contour code to use lists.
I have given an example of my data and the code I am currently using below.
Thanks in advance for any help given. Holly

Data set:

```
Grade <- structure(list(Eastings = c(156000L, 156010L, 156421L, 156450L, 156500L, 156700L, 158420L, 158646L, 158970L, 159050L, 159050L, 159130L, 159155L), Northings = c(143630, 143980, 147260, 145000, 146000, 142800, 146700, 145207, 147170, 145200, 144800, 147815, 145890), Zn = c(2, 8, 4, 0, 3, 0, 2, 7, 12, 0, 4, 19, 0)), .Names = c("Eastings", "Northings", "Zn"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
library(ggplot2)
Grade <- read.csv(file="filename.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
ggplot(data=Grade, aes(x=Eastings, y=Northings, z=Zn)) +
stat_density2d(aes(fill=..level..), contour=TRUE, geom="polygon") +
geom_density2d(colour="red", size=0.2)
```

[image: Current code results]

Comment: Might be worth making your example fully reproducible in a fresh R session. Should `Grade <- Statsrep`? Also, even when I do that, I don't get the plot shown. (Plus, the call to `read.csv()` is unnecessary here, right?)

Comment: Apologies, I forgot to change the Statsrep. The data I have given here is an edited data set as the one used to make the plot belongs to a company who haven't published the results yet. I have included the read.csv section just in case this section of code is different to call up data in lists or a matrix

Comment: I think maybe you'll have more luck looking at the examples in `?stat_contour`, although your example data appears to be too sparse to estimate contours directly.

Comment: The example data is not my true data set. I have about 116 points. I have tried using stat_contour but have always had the following error: Error in contourLines (x = sort(unique(data$x)), y = sort (unique(data$y)), : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'. I think it is because ggplot2 contouring requires a regular grid and my map coordinates don't have a regular spacing.